# AngularJs To Do list Directive

Tags: angularjs

**Edit**
JS Fiddle added [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHaworth/LyWHz/5/)

I'm trying to learn AngularJs and so I'm trying to take the "To Do" application to the next level.

Instead of an item being done or not, I want to have three states: (status)

- 0 = Waiting
- 1 = Working
- 2 = Completed

I also want to have a priority:

- 1 = High
- 2 = Medium
- 3 = Low

Here is my data:

```
[
  {"taskId":1,"description":"Test 1.","priority":1,"status":0}
  {"taskId":2,"description":"Test 2.","priority":1,"status":0}
  {"taskId":3,"description":"Test 3.","priority":1,"status":1}
]
```

I've got three lists that displays each status wonderfully. When I move an item from one status to another, it goes away from the original list and appears in the appropriate list for the new status.

However, I am now working with directives and I want to turn those three separate lists into a single directive and it's really kicking my butt.

This is the hard-coded version of my To-Do list that displays the To-Do items in a 'Waiting' status.

```
<h3 style="display: inline-block;">Waiting</h3>
<div class="label" style="display: inline-block;" ng-hide="getStatusCount(0) == 0">{{getStatusCount(0)}}</div>
    <div class="infoTableWrap">
    <table class="infoTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left">Description</th>
                <th style="text-align: right">Priority</th>
                <th style="text-align: right">Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks.items | filter:{status:0}">
                <td style="text-align: left">{{task.description}}</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">
                    <select name="ddlPriority" ng-model="task.priority" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in priorityOptions"></select>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: right">
                    <select name="ddlStatus" ng-model="task.status" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in statusOptions"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my attempt at making that a directive

```
<script type="text/template" id="taskListTemplate">
    <h3 style="display: inline-block;">{{header}}</h3>
    <div class="label" style="display: inline-block;" ng-hide="getStatusCount(2) == 0">{{getStatusCount(2)}}</div>
    <div class="infoTableWrap">
        <table class="infoTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: left">Description</th>
                    <th style="text-align: right">Priority</th>
                    <th style="text-align: right">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="task in taskList | filter:{status:2}">
                    <td style="text-align: left">{{task.description}}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <select name="ddlPriority" ng-model="task.priority" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in priorityOptions"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <select name="ddlStatus" ng-model="task.status" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in statusOptions"></select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is how I'm calling it:

```
div task-list-directive header="Completed Tasks" status-type="2" task-list="tasks.items"></div>
```

And here is the directive code

```
.directive("taskListDirective", function() {
return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {
        header: "@",
        taskList: "=",
        statusType: "@"
    },
    template: function () {
    return angular.element(document.querySelector("#taskListTemplate")).html();
    }
};
})
```

What works:

- Header (the header is coming across just fine)
- taskList (the task list is coming across just fine)

What doesn't work in the directive:

- Setting the statusType so I don't have to hard-code the 2 in the template
- The lists come up empty, but I figure that's a scope thing and I was going to turn those into directives as well.

Thanks,
Duane

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHaworth/LyWHz/5/)

I included the form to add new items...and there are two hard coded lists for "Waiting" and "Working"...and I commented out the html for the directive as I couldn't get that to work in JSFiddle.

Comment: Any chance you can make a Plunker or JSFiddle?

Comment: ng-hidden? Does that even exist?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  :-)  That would explain why it never worked.  I was to focused on the other issues.  But it's been fixed and the JSFiddle updated.  Thanks for the catch!  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to reference `statusType` in your directive and use it to filter on.

```
ng-repeat="task in taskList | filter:{status:statusType}"
```

and

```
{{getStatusCount(statusType)}}
```

Since the directive uses isolated scope, you can't reference `priorityOptions` and `statusOptions` that are in the controller.  You could pass them in the same way you do with `taskList`.  But you could also define a controller for the directive and put those things there.  Here I've done both.  Since you also use `priorityOptions` in your form, I kept it in the controller and passed it in to the directive.  Since `statusOptions` is only used in the directive, I moved it out of the controller.

```
.directive("taskListDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "EAC",
        scope: {
            header: "@",
            taskList: "=",
            priorityOptions: "=",
            statusType: "@"
        },
        template: function () {
            return angular.element(document.querySelector("#taskListTemplate")).html();
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.getStatusCount = function (statusType) {
                return countStatusTypes(statusType);
            }

            //Private Methods
            function countStatusTypes(statusType) {
                var count = 0;
                angular.forEach($scope.taskList, function (item) {
                    if (item.status === statusType * 1) {
                        count++;
                    }
                });
                return count;
            }               

            $scope.statusOptions = [{
                name: 'Waiting',
                id: 0
            }, {
                name: 'Working',
                id: 1
            }, {
                name: 'Completed',
                id: 2
            }];
        }
    };
});
```

Here's your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/MAL5n/2/) updated to use the directly exclusively.

Comment: Here's a follow up as I continue to make enhancements: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120549/angularjs-directives-with-dropdown-lists