# AngularJs Directives with DropDown lists

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Perhaps I'm aiming too big with my reusable directive idea, but I've been asked to give a demo for my company in less than two weeks, so I'm aiming higher than normal.

I'm building on top of another question I asked and was answered here: 
[Angular to do list directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24092275/angularjs-to-do-list-directive)

I've added some new features, such as "Click to edit".

Here's my [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OFVWyZsGa68sRv4lwkin?p=preview)

Here's what works:

- Click to edit

Here's what I'm having problems with:

- Display text instead of ID from drop down list
- Auto-focus object to force input to have focus so I can really capture blur

Next question will be:

- How do I know what object I'm updating to send back to the server?

I did spend all day Sunday trying to get those tasks to work, but failed.  I cleaned up the code of most of my failed attempts.

I do want to save the record each time I edit a field.  I get that I'm updating the object,  which I think is beautiful, but I don't know what to trigger to send the object back to the server.  Perhaps that's the jQuery background talking?

Thanks,
Duane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To display text instead of ID from dropdown list**:

You can create a function in the directive that loops through the options, and returns the `name` when the `id` matches the value you're binding on.  For example:

```
scope.statusText = function(){
  var text = '';
  angular.forEach(scope.statusOptions, function(item){
    if(item.id == scope.task.status)
        text = item.name;
    });
    return text;
}
```

**To auto-focus the element**

Create a function in the directive that is called on the `ng-click` of the "display" span.  This will set `scope.editStatusMode = true`, then call `.focus` on the element.

```
scope.setStatusFocus = function(){
  scope.editStatusMode = true;
  var el = element.find('select');
  $timeout(function(){
    el.focus();
  });
};
```

Wrapping the `el.focus()` in `$timeout` will delay the call to focus until the DOM is done rendering.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<span ng-hide="editStatusMode" ng-click="setStatusFocus()" ng-bind="statusText()"></span>
```

**How do you know which object you're updating**

Create an `update()` function in the directive that is bound to 'ng-blur`.  In that function, you can access`scope.task`, which you can send off to your server to save.

```
scope.update = function(){
  scope.editPriorityMode = false;
  //Save scope.task here.
  console.log(scope.task);
}
```

This works for `description` and `priority`.  It doesn't work for `status` because when you change the status, it immediately disappears from whichever list it is in and is added to a different list, and the `blur` event is never fired.  To deal with `status`, you can create a `$watch` on `task.status`, and call the `update()` function from there.

```
scope.$watch('task.status', function(oldValue, newValue){
  scope.update();
})
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MBwAUkPZvYUhDAVW7KZN?p=preview)

Comment: Once again...thank you very much.  I did change ng-blur to ng-change on the ddlPriorty select box to get it to behave like the ddlStatus select box....and that works great in Plunker land...but I'm not getting it to work right in the real world.  How long have you been doing Angular and what resources did you use to learn it?

Thanks a million!

Comment: I'm certainly not an Angular expert.  I've actually learned the most from trying to answer SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you got more than one question I'll answer what I can and then edit with other answers:

**Display text instead of ID from drop down list:** There is different solutions to this problem. You could use a simple lodash method to find the value of the id you have selected (`_.find(priorityOptions, {value: task.priority})`). You could actually save the `(id, name)` pair inside your `ngModel` (`task.priority`) so then you can refer to `task.priority.name` in your span.

**Auto-focus object to force input to have focus so I can really capture blur**: You can call a function inside your ng-click on the span that handles that behaviour and makes sure that the focus will be the input field and also binds a blur event for when you click away.

**How do I know what object I'm updating to send back to the server:** If you want to send the changes to the server when you blur a field (which, by the way, you can simply do with adding the attribute `ng-blur="update()"` to your input elements) you can access the `scope` of the element you are on (`scope.task`) and send it through a `dataFactory` method.

Comment: Thanks...I'm experimenting now with #1 (Display Text instead of id) right now trying to get that to work.

The Auto-Focus issue is that once you click on something to edit, it doesn't have the focus, so you can open everything for edit and I'd rather just have one input element open at a time.